# How to add external data folder into developing R package?

Tags: r, package, r-package

Hi I could find many resources on reading external file into a developing package like this https://r-pkgs.org/data.html . But is it even possible to read an external data folder into a package ? Instead of passing a file (or data frame), I would like to pass a folder like from GitHub or can someone recommend any other ways on how people approach this problem ?

Comment: Yes, it is possible, but you haven't really described your problem clearly enough here - what have you tried so far, and where did you get stuck? What's wrong with just having the folder as a subdirectory of `inst` in your package's source files?

Comment: Relevant doc: https://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/r-release/R-exts.html#Data-in-packages

Comment: "External" data in this context doesn't refer to data from anywhere; it refers to data from somewhere in your package other than the `data` directory, usually `inst/extdata`.

Comment: From [here](https://r-pkgs.org/intro.html), "In R, the fundamental unit of shareable code is the package. A package bundles together code, data, documentation, and tests...".  Thus, without further explanation, the concept of "reading external file into a developing package" seems to be an oxymoron.

Comment: Thanks. @MikaelJagan These files are consumed within a function in my package. So a function within my package is calling is calling an external package that use these files.

Comment: Then include that package as a dependency of your package in `DESCRIPTION`, and use `system.file` to obtain relevant paths from inside your function.